# Por quê meu app ionic não roda no navegador?

Tags: ionic

Fiz um app com ionic e roda perfeitamente usando comando `ionic serve`. Mas quando tento rodar ele no navegador não funciona direito, por quê isso?

Ao rodar o app no navegador aparece a seguinte aviso no console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < (index):1

E esse é só um dos problemas.
A validação do login, por exemplo, se coloco um login diferente não aparece a mensagem que coloquei "E-mail ou senha inválido"! Está entrando sem problemas no app.

Comment: Você está usando algum plugin do cordova no projeto? Se estiver só vai funcionar no mobile mesmo, no browser algumas função não serão possíveis.

Comment: Como o amigo André Vicente disse, se você utiliza algumas funções do cordova a mesma só vai funcionar se estiver num ambiente mobile e/ou emulando com o ionic serve. Não faço ideia como esses frameworks conseguem fazer chamadas a funções nativas, mas acredito que seja por meio de um [JavascriptInterface][1] que te possibilita fazer essas chamadas (não sei, é só um palpite), e se isso estiver certo, essa interface não existira no ambiente web (como disse, é um palpite)


  [1]: http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/webkit/JavascriptInterface.html